# How to achieve staggering effect on ng-repeat items

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, ng-animate

My code is structured in the following manner:

**Base HTML**

```
<div class="section_loaded" ui-view="section_loaded" ng-animate-children="true" ></div>
```

and the state injecting content into that ui-view directive is as follows:

**Inside App.js**

```
.state("main", {
url:"/",
views:{
  "section_loaded@main": {
    templateUrl: _urlPrefixes.TEMPLATES + "components/Main/Main.html",
    controller: "MainController",
  },
}
```

})

My Main.html is as follows:

**Main.html**

```
  <ul>
  <li class="menu_options" ui-sref="donald_main.music" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <div class="menu_container">
      <div class="menu_item_top_section">
        <img src="dist/img/[[tab.icon]]" alt="[[tab.name]] Icon">
      </div>
      <div class="menu_item_bottom_section">
        <p>[[tab.name]]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>      
</ul>
```

I am trying to animate ng-repeat using a staggering effect using the following scss

**main.scss**

```
 [ui-view].ng-enter{
  .Main_Container{
  transition:0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-50px);

   .menu_options{
     transform: translateY(-10px);
     opacity: 0;
     &.ng-enter-stagger{
       transition-delay: 0.3s;
       transition-duration: 0;
     }
   }
}
}
```

I am trying to achieve a staggering sliding-in animation on the elements generated by ng-repeat using the above css code. The best I could achieve was that the elements do slide in all at once but I could not get the staggering effect to work. Am I doing something wrong in the code provided above? I have searched all over the net but all results point to the css I have provided which does not seem to work. I am using ng-animate v1.6.3.

Comment: This cannot be done on initial page loading. `ng-animate` blocks animations during initial page loading

Comment: So whats the work around. I have seen items animating when a view changes, how do they achieve it?

Comment: On second thought, I am managing to animate when the view loads, its just the staggering effect that is not working